# Google Maps marker multi-select issue

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-maps, multi-select

So I'm currently trying to make all of my filters on my markers multi-select. The problem I run into is:

If I want to look for all the active people, i press the dropdown and click on active. The dropdown then closes and gives me all the active people. But let's say I want to see the active and inactive people. I click the dropdown again, and click on inactive. Every marker disappears. I think this has something to do, with the for loop not registering markers that are invisible i.e `marker.setVisible(false);`

So I tried both putting `marker.setVisible(true);` and `marker.setMap(map);` but the issue still percists. I think I need to make all the markers visible, so that it can get a clean look at all the markers. Maybe I'm wrong and I'm missing something. Here is my current code:

JS:

```
filterMarkers = function(fieldID){


        var selective = document.getElementById(fieldID).options;

        var arrayOfSelectedIDs = [];

        for (i = 0; i < selective.length; i++)
        {
          if (selective[i].selected){
            arrayOfSelectedIDs.push(selective[i].value)
          }
        }
        console.log(arrayOfSelectedIDs);

        for (i = 0; i < gmarkers.length; i++)
        {
          marker = gmarkers[i];
          marker.setMap(map)
          marker.setVisible(true);
          console.log(gmarkers.length);

          if (marker.status.includes(arrayOfSelectedIDs)) 
          {
            marker.setVisible(true);
          }
          else {
            marker.setVisible(false);
          }
```

HTML:

```
<select class="status-multiple" required name="status[]" multiple="multiple" id="status" onchange="filterMarkers(this.id);" style="width: 7%;">
  <option></option>
  <option value="Active">Aktiv</option>
  <option value="Inactive">Inaktiv</option>
  <option value="Prospective">Prospective</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Is that all of the `filterMarkers ` except for the 2 closing curly braces?

Comment: the full code would be useful

Comment: Yes it is. I've and pushed all of the markers inside this array.

Comment: I can upload the full code, but all of the css, js and html is in one file (Not my choice)

Comment: https://pastecode.io/s/9r8w8i8r

Comment: I have had a quick look though your code and I don't think I'd be wrong saying that there is room for refinement.  There is a considerable amount of duplication here and it is always (IMO) more preferable to use JSON (with named parameters as an Object) to an array with numeric indices.

Comment: It also appears that this is based around some form of templating library but no indication as to which. Perhaps add that as a tag and it'll help attract others from that field of interest?!

Comment: As many ( a lot ) of the `select` menus use the same `filterMarkers` function to filter the markers shown you'll need to update some sort of global variable so that each dropdown can check this variable... there is, quite simply, too much to try to comprehend here

Comment: a little more thought after some sleep - because there are many dropdown menus using this `filter` type mechanism the choices selected in all menus must be used to determine whether or not a particular marker is visible or not does it not? Initially I thought a global variable but not so sure that would be the way- very hard to know without being able to run the code

Comment: How could I make it produce only one marker, with all the information I need, and still make it work

Comment: Why would you wish to `"produce only one marker, with all the information I need"` ? I don't understand....

Comment: I don't know. I just want to fix this issue, and I'm kind of lsot

Comment: Let me clarify if I may. You have several `select` menus all using the same `filterMarkers` function. The purpose of this function is to show markers of the category selected by the user? For example if the user selects from 3 dropdown menus the filtering is to include markers based upon the values chosen in all 3 dropdowns and any markers not meeting this criteria will be hidden?

Comment: Yes. That's what I want to achieve

Comment: Without the actual data I don't know how far I can actually progress the filter mechanism I have. It works in my tests with my data - I can share the `"bare bones"` of it and let you adapt it to your data unless you can add some/all the data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without the data to build a functional demo no final testing could be done but the following mechanism works OK for my map/data. The only piece of the puzzle I have not tested is the filtering of multiple items from a single select menu - the portion f code within `markers.filter()` may need further thought for that to work 100%! However if you run the snippet you'll see the filters being built and this should give a good idea what is happening or going to happen but was unable to test without data.

I took the `select` menus from your code and modified them down a little by adding a `className` by which to target them and changing the ID to a name. I hope you'll be able to see how you can utilise this and adapt it to your code.

```js
/*
  The `select` menus all have an initial option that has no value
  and negates that `select` menu from the final filtering if it is
  selected. Without that initial empty option there would be no means
  by which the filter could be removed.
*/

let markers=[
  /*
    this is an array of the markers. Each marker has attributes that can 
    be targeted by these filters - such as `gender`, `grade`, `tutor_gym`
    
    We can check a markers property like: mkr.grade or mkr.gender etc
    which will be done by the logic in the filtering function - 
    ie:
    markers.filter()
    
    
  */
];

let filters={};
let CN='filtered';





const filterMarkers=function(e){
  // add/remove `filtered` class depending upon option selected
  if( this.selectedIndex==0 && this.classList.contains( CN ) ){
    this.classList.remove( CN );
    if( this.hasAttribute('multiple') ){
        [...this.options].forEach((o,i)=>{
          if( filters.hasOwnProperty(`${this.name}[${i}]`) )delete filters[`${this.name}[${i}]`];
        });
    }else{
      delete filters[ this.name ];
    }
  }else this.classList.add( CN );

  // hide all markers
  if( markers )markers.forEach( mkr=>mkr.setVisible( false ) );



  /* 
    process ALL select menus
    ------------------------
    Stage 1: prepare filters
    Stage 2: filter the markers array based upon filters
    Stage 3: display markers returned after filtering.
  */

  // 1 - prepare
  let col=document.querySelectorAll( `select.${CN}` );
    col.forEach( n=>{
      if( n.hasAttribute('multiple') ){
      
        // delete filters where there is the multiple attribute set
        [...n.options].forEach((o,i)=>{
          if( filters.hasOwnProperty(`${n.name}[${i}]`) )delete filters[`${n.name}[${i}]`];
        });
        
        // then add only those selected options to the filters...
        [ ...n.selectedOptions ].forEach((obj,i)=>{
          filters[ `${n.name}[${i}]`]=obj.value;
        })

      }else{
        filters[ n.name ]=n.value;
      }
    });
    
    // this will show what filters will be applied
    console.log( filters );

    // 2 - filter
    let filtered=markers.filter( function( mkr ){
      let res=true;
      Object.keys( filters ).forEach( ( name, i ) => {
        res = res && filters[ name ]===mkr[ name ];
      });
      return res;
    });

    // 3 - display
    filtered.forEach( mkr=>{
      mkr.setVisible( true );
    }); 
};
const filterSecond=(e)=>console.log('hello world');




document.querySelectorAll('select.usr-select').forEach( n=>n.addEventListener('change',filterMarkers));
document.querySelector('select.usr-second-select').addEventListener('change',filterSecond );
```

```css
body,
body * {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#map {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  float: none;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
form {
  width: 800px;
  float: none;
  margin: 1rem auto;
}
select,
[type='text']{
  padding: 0.25rem;
  margin: 0.1rem;
}
option:first-child {
  background: grey;
  color: white;
  font-style:italic;
  text-decoration:underline;
}
.filtered {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1rem rgba(0, 255, 0, 1)
}
```

```html
<form>
  <select class='usr-select status-multiple' required name='status' multiple='multiple' name='status'>
    <option selected>Status
    <option value='Active'>Aktiv
    <option value='Inactive'>Inaktiv
    <option value='Prospective'>Prospective
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='gymtype'>
    <option selected>Gym type
    <option value='STX'>STX
    <option value='HHX'>HHX
    <option value='HTX'>HTX
    <option value='HF'>HF
    <option value='IB'>IB
    <option value='IBB'>IBB
    <option value='EUX'>EUX
    <option value='EUD'>EUD
    <option value='Foreign high school'>Foreign high school
    <option value='Other'>Other
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='still_gym'>
    <option selected>Gym år
    <option value='1.g'>1.g
    <option value='2.g'>2.g
    <option value='3.g'>3.g
    <option value='Jeg er færdig med gymnasiet'>Færdig
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='gender' class='ui dropdown'>
    <option selected>Gender
    <option value='Mand'>Male
    <option value='Kvinde'>Female
    <option value='Other'>Other  
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='car'>
    <option selected>Adgang til bil
    <option value='Yes'>Ja
    <option value='No'>Nej
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='grade'>
    <option selected>Karakter
    <option value='Under 7'>Under 7
    <option value='7 til 8'>7 til 8
    <option value='8 til 9'>8 til 9
    <option value='9 til 10'>9 til 10
    <option value='10 til 11'>10 til 11
    <option value='11 til 12'>11 til 12
    <option value='Over 12'>Over 12
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='course'>
    <option selected>Online prioriteringer
    <option value='1. prioritet (Bor i mindre by)'>1. prioritet (Bor i mindre by)
    <option value='2. prioritet (Foretrækker online)'>2. prioritet (Foretrækker online)
    <option value='3. prioritet (Bor i større by)'>3. prioritet (Bor i større by)
    <option value='4. prioritet (Foretrækker fysisk)'>4. prioritet (Foretrækker fysisk)
    <option value='5. prioritet (Kan ikke undervise online)'>5. prioritet (Kan ikke undervise online)
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='programs' >
    <option selected>Programmer
    <option value='Excel'>Excel
    <option value='TI-Nspire'>TI-Nspire
    <option value='Geogebra'>Geogebra
    <option value='Wordmat'>Wordmat
    <option value='Maple'>Maple
    <option value='Matlab'>Matlab
    <option value='STATA'>STATA
    <option value='JMP'>JMP
    <option value='R'>R
    <option value='Python'>Python
    <option value='Maple'>Maple
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='fluent_danish'>
    <option selected>Snakker dansk?
    <option value='Yes'>Ja
    <option value='No'>Nej
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='fluent_other'>
    <option selected>Flydende i
    <option value='Engelsk'>English
    <option value='Tsyk'>German
    <option value='Fransk'>French
    <option value='Spansk'>Spanish
    <option value='Arabisk'>Arabic
    <option value='Portugisisk'>Portugesse
    <option value='Russisk'>Russian
    <option value='Japansk'>Japanesse
    <option value='Kinesisk'>Chinesse
    <option value='Persisk'>Persian
    <option value='Italiensk'>Italian
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='more_courses'>
    <option selected>Åben for forløb?
    <option value='Yes'>Ja
    <option value='No'>Nej
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='educational_institution'>
    <option selected>Uddannelsesinstitution
    <option value='Aalborg Universitet'>Aalborg Uni
    <option value='Aarhus Universitet'>Aarhus Uni
    <option value='Absalon Professionshøjskole'>Absalon Professionshøjskole
    <option value='Copenhagen Business Academy'>Copenhagen Business Academy
    <option value='Copenhagen Business School'>Copenhagen Business School
    <option value='Danmarks Tekniske Universitet'>Danmarks Tekniske Uni
    <option value='Danmarks Medie- og Jornalisthøjskole'>DMJX
    <option value='Erhvervsakademi Aarhus'>Erhvervsakademi Aarhus
    <option value='Erhvervsakademi Dania'>Erhvervsakademi Dania
    <option value='Erhvervsakademi Kolding'>Erhvervsakademi Kolding
    <option value='Erhvervsakademi Midtvest'>Erhvervsakademi Midtvest
    <option value='Erhvervsakademi Sydvest'>Erhvervsakademi Sydvest
    <option value='IT-Universitet'>IT-Uni
    <option value='Københavns Universitet'>KU
    <option value='Københavns Professionshøjskole'>Københavns Professionshøjskole
    <option value='Københavns Erhvervsakademi'>Københavns Erhvervsakademi
    <option value='Professionshøjskolen UCN'>Professionshøjskolen
    <option value='Roskilde Universitet'>Roskilde Uni
    <option value='SmartLearning'>SmartLearning
    <option value='Syddansk Universitet'>Syddansk Uni
    <option value='UC Syd'>IT-Uni
    <option value='UCL Erhvervsakademi og Professionshøjskole'>UCL
    <option value='Via University College'>Via University College
    <option value='Zealand'>Zealand
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='age_interval'>
    <option selected>Alder
    <option value='under 18'>Under 18
    <option value='18 til 20'>18 til 20
    <option value='21 til 23'>21 til 23
    <option value='24 til 26'>24 til 26
    <option value='27+'>Over 27
  </select>

  <select class='usr-second-select' name='secondAddress'>
    <option selected>Sekundær adresse
    <option value='hide'>Skjul sekundær adresse  
    <option value='show'>Vis sekundær adresse
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='hour_interval'>
    <option selected>Time interval
    <option value='0 til 2'>0 til 2
    <option value='2 til 10'>2 til 10
    <option value='10 til 50'>10 til 50
    <option value='50 til 100'>50 til 100
    <option value='100+'>Over 100
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='qualification'>
    <option selected>Kvalifikationer
    <option value='Super pædagogisk'>Pædagogisk 
    <option value='Ikke særlig pædagogisk'>Ikke Pædagogisk 
    <option value='Dansk korrektur/grammatik'>Dansk korrektur/gramamtik
    <option value='Engelsk korrektur/grammatik'>Engelsk korrektur/grammatik
    <option value='God til SRP-forløb'>God til SRP-forløb
    <option value='God til sprogundervisning'>God til sprogundervisning
  </select>

  <!--
  
    these had dynamic content - templating engine??
  
  -->
  <select class='usr-select' name='subject'>
    <option selected>Fag
    <!--
      more options...
    -->
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='uni'>
    <option selected>Uni Uddannelser
  </select>

  <select class='usr-select' name='tutor_gym'>
    <option selected>Tutorens gym
  </select>


  <input type='text' name='pac-input' class='controls' placeholder='Søg efter adresse' />
</form>
<div id='map'># MAP #</div>
```

A working example utilising this approach can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/RamRaider/2xwg5hro/5/)

Comment: How can I make this compatible with the Select2 library from JQuery. I'm using it for making multi-select

Comment: To be perfectly honest I have absolutely no idea. I do not use jQuery at all and have such basic knowledge of jQuery I would not know where to start. Did the above help at all though? If yes ...perhaps accept answer, if No... I'll chalk it down to experience!